# koa-router, отрисовка после post запроса

Tags: node.js, reactjs, koa.js

Не понимаю как отрисовать React компонент после post запроса.
Post делаю через curl в терминале. Ответ - html в виде строки.
Если поменять post на get то все отрисовывается без проблема.

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import koaRouter from 'koa-router';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import Application from '../application';

const app = new Koa();
const api = koaRouter();

api.post('/post',
// api.get('/',
  async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.body = await renderToString(<Application />);
    return next();
  }
);

app.use(api.routes());
app.use(api.allowedMethods());
app.listen(3000);
```